# Add class to vector doesnt work

Tags: c++

i have the following problem:

I have two classes:

FooClass.h

```
#include <vector>
#include "BaseClass.h"

using namespace std;
class FooClass
{
public:
    vector<BaseClass> vBaseClass;

    void doStuff();
    void addBaseClass(BaseClass &baseClass);
};
```

FooClass.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "FooClass.h"



    void FooClass::doStuff()
    {
        cout << "Well nice done" << endl;
    }

    void FooClass::addBaseClass(BaseClass &baseClass)
    {
         baseClass.updateData(this);
        vBaseClass.push_back(baseClass);
    }
```

And

BaseClass.h

```
#include "FooClass.h"

class BaseClass {
public:
    void updateData(FooClass *pFooClass);

};
```

BaseClass.cpp

```
#include "BaseClass.h"


void BaseClass::updateData(FooClass *pFooClass)
{
    //We try to get some data, and if we get the data we call pFooClass->doStuff
    pFooClass->doStuff();
}
```

So, basically the function should be that i create one instance of FooClass.
Then i create multiple instances of BaseClass which i want to add to the vBaseClass vector in the FooClass.
If needet i want to access the BaseClass instance with vBaseClass[key] and call the doStuff() function in FooClass. I give FooClass as a pointer parameter because i want to have still access to the vBaseClass vector from the doStuff() function then which is called by an BaseClass instance.

Everything works fine, but when i add the vector i get the following errors:

```
error: ‘BaseClass’ was not declared in this scope
     vector<BaseClass> vBaseClass;
error: template argument 1 is invalid
     vector<BaseClass> vBaseClass;
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: ‘BaseClass’ has not been declared
     void addBaseClass(BaseClass &baseClass);
error: ‘FooClass’ has not been declared
     void updateData(FooClass *pFooClass);
 error: no matching function for call to ‘BaseClass::updateData(FooClass*)’
 baseClass.updateData(this);
```

If someone knows the solution, many thanks!

Comment: You have a circular inclusion: `FooClass.h` - `BaseClass.h`. Also you lack include guards...

Comment: Thanks, How can i solve this? I also added another line fooclass.cpp where i call baseClass.updateData(this); This gives me another error i addet.  error: no matching function for call to ‘BaseClass::updateData(FooClass*)’
 baseClass.updateData(this);

Comment: you need a forward-declaration of one of the classes.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, my issue is solved, here is the working code:

FooClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTPROJECT_FOOCLASS_H
#define TESTPROJECT_FOOCLASS_H
#include <vector>
#include "BaseClass.h"

using namespace std;

class BaseClass;

class FooClass
{
public:
    vector<BaseClass> vBaseClass;

    void doStuff();
    void addBaseClass(BaseClass &baseClass);
};
#endif //TESTPROJECT_FOOCLASS_H
```

FooClass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FooClass.h"



void FooClass::doStuff()
{
    cout << "Well nice done" << endl;
}

void FooClass::addBaseClass(BaseClass &baseClass)
{
    baseClass.updateData(this);
    vBaseClass.push_back(baseClass);
}
```

BaseClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTPROJECT_BASECLASS_H
#define TESTPROJECT_BASECLASS_H
#include "FooClass.h"

class FooClass;
class BaseClass {
public:
    void updateData(FooClass *pFooClass);

};

#endif //TESTPROJECT_BASECLASS_H
```

BaseClass.cpp

```
#include "BaseClass.h"


void BaseClass::updateData(FooClass *pFooClass)
{
    //We try to get some data, and if we get the data we call pFooClass->doStuff
    pFooClass->doStuff();
}
```

main.cpp // console output "Well nice done"

```
#include "lib/FooClass.h"

int main()
{
    FooClass fooclass;
    BaseClass baseclass;
    fooclass.addBaseClass(baseclass);

}
```

Thanks to everyone, it is my first activity and question here and i am really impressed how fast i got answers, really thanks!

#

Because i got asked to say what the issue was and how i solved it, i addet

to FooClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTPROJECT_FOOCLASS_H
#define TESTPROJECT_FOOCLASS_H

class BaseClass;
```

and to BaseClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTPROJECT_BASECLASS_H
#define TESTPROJECT_BASECLASS_H

class FooClass;
```

So the main issue was that i had to declare BaseClass and FooClass as shown above in the header of each others class.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using g++, g++ --version outputs: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: If you can add more details on what a. Was the issue, b. How did forward declaring fix it, this answer would be complete and helpful to other people with similar issues. As it stands right now your answer is more appropriate to be a comment

Comment: Yes okay, i will update the post above this comments here after i got some sleep now, i will reproduce the problem with my first code and then describe the steps which helped. Thats also a good way really to learn thanks :)

Comment: Addet the explanation.